# PolygonSprite in LibGdx shows only part of the Texture.

Tags: java, android, libgdx, polygon

i have got this beautiful looking image:

[image]

I decided to use the PolygonSprite class in LiGgdx to display a part of that Image.

It ended up looking like that:
[image]

As you can see the very left corner of my image is visible.

Here comes my question:
What can i do to display a larger part of that image inside the polygonSprite above, without changing the polygonSprite's size ?

I do really appreciate any answer and please don't hesitate to ask if something isn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used it myself, but looking at the documentation it looks like this: you have to create the polygonsprite with a correct polygonregion (vertices with pixel coordinates of the texture) and then use setSize to "scale" it to the size you want to display it (world/viewport coordinates).

Comment: THANK YOU MAN, that totally worked out!! Absolutely Fantastic!! Good Work!!
Can you give me the link for that documentation?